# Good ways of removing rows from large data sets in pandas and when to use copy()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When working with smaller data sets, I don't seem to have a problem with using something like:

```
df=df[df.Column_Name !='Some Value I want to sort by']
```

then, later in the program:

```
df=df[df.Another_Column_Name != 'Something else I want to sort by']
```

and using to filter the data set to some subset of data. However when I have larger datasets, this becomes unreliable. There aren't any warning and I think what is happening is that I must be operating on some view of the data rather than having the data actually being changed.

Is the proper way to do this to use the `.copy()` command to make sure that I avoid this issue using.

```
df=df[df.Column_Name !='Some Value I want to sort by'].copy()
```

Or should I be eliminating rows a different way. Obviously this wastes memory. I don't want to use for loops since that slows everything down. Is there an easy way to understand how much memory a data object is using?

Comment: Are you sure the example represents your situation?
There could be problem of "Setting on a copy" when you do:  df[column][idx] = value, but in your case the assignment should always work

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the problem in the pivot table of the excell table I was using to verify my program against. Things seems to be working consistently now.